# How to identify simulink blocks contributing to unstable pole during linearization

Tags: matlab, stability, linear-algebra

I have a simulink model resulting in a state space model using linearization at a steady state condition. The resulting statespace model of order 135 shows an unstable pole contributed by a particular block/path in the model. However, when use stabsep command, the resulting linear part has 134 states which are all stable. The nonlinear model has one state which is unstable. Can anyone help with any link/suggestion how to identify the block which caused the unstable state

Comment: Why/how do you have a state-space model with 135 states??

Comment: The model is a co-simulation model having a plant fmu with 10 inputs and 20 outputs. There are other parts of the controls taking measurement from the plant and converting it to a another variable for error computation against the reference. The controls is using a cascade architecture. I am currently limited to linearizing the inner loop identifying the open loop TF of inner loop which shows 135 states. I used linearization manager with option of state ordering. However, simulink is unable to list path of state and block links as it exceeds 100 states

Comment: ....but state feedback control is for SISO systems. What are you doing here? I don't understand how you're planning to make use of a 10-input, 20-output system. Do you have a diagram of the model you can share?

Comment: Thank you Chuck. Unfortunately, I cannot share the information of the system considering security

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to Mathworks directly for support then. Maybe there's a mechanism that would identify the issue for you.

Comment: Thank you Chuck. I would contact Mathworks too